# Refresh captcha image?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, captcha

I have an action method returns an image file `captcha`, and I don't know how to implement a button to refresh this `captcha`.  I think I should use `Jquery` because I don't want this page re-load but I don't know how to implement that

**This my Action method:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var captcha = new DemoMVC2112.Models.CenterCaptcha();
        Session["captcha"] = captcha.Text;
        return File(captcha.ImageAsByteArray, "image/png");
    }
```

**Div captcha at View:**

```
 <div class="captchaImage">
  <img src='@Url.Action("Index", "CaptchaImage")' id="captchaImage" /> <button id="Refresh_Captcha">ReFresh CaptCha</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding like this,i hope this will fix your issue

then bind the captcha by adding date to refresh the content of captcha

```
   function reloadCaptcha()
   {
     document.getElementById('captchaImage').src = 
     document.getElementById('captchaIMage').src+ '?' new Date().getTime();
   }
```